# how replace a tag with attribute to string empty?

Tags: php, regex

How i can replace a string from:

```
"this is a <p id="1" /> text <p id="2" /> of a string"
```

To:

```
"this is a <br> text <br> of a string" ?
```

Shortly i want replace all `<p ... />` present in a string with `<br>`.

Comment: Str_replace will work or if u have multiple p tag than use regex

Comment: i can't use str_replace becouse attribute of <p ... /> not is a costant.

Comment: Now u have few solutions given below try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**: (just `<p ... />`)

```
echo preg_replace("/<p[^\/]*\/>/i", "<br />", 'this is a <p id="1" /> text <p id="2" /> of a string');
```

Comment: This will add br in closing tag also

Comment: Fine bro. Also chk my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace()` along with `str_replace()`

```
$newString = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $yourString); // will remove all starting tag
$addNewLine = str_replace("</p>", "<br />", $newString); // will replace closing tag with <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace("<p id=\"d\"/>", "<br>", "this is a <p id=\"1\" /> text <p id=\"2\" /> of a string");
?>
```

You'll get:

```
this is a

text

of a string
```

Comment: What about closing p tag?